# Finding topographic prominence of peaks in a 2D heightmap

Tags: c++, terrain, heightmap, topography

Is there a (preferably simple) algorithm for finding [topographic prominence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topographic_prominence) of peaks in a 2D heightmap? I'd like to find how prominent each local maximum is.  I'm toying with good old terrain generation and I'd like the generator to identify prominent mountains/peaks. Trying to implement this in C++.

[Here's a screenshot for clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uRIE.jpg) White ticks mark the peaks (found by brute force). I want to determine the prominence for each of them.

Comment: Not sure if this would work, but maybe you could use binary search on different intervals to find the first point where `f(x) >= f(x+1)` (the peaks), then from each peak scan to the left/right to find the prominence?

Comment: You probably have a brute force approach. Please show it as a [mre] as a clarification of input and desired result.

Comment: I'm using brute force to find actual peaks, just iterating through all points and checking if all 8 neighbours are lower. But that's not the problem, I'm fine with brute force here. The question is how to calculate prominence (as defined in linked wiki page) of such peaks.

Comment: Added an image to question, hope that makes things a bit clearer.